# Changing symbology of the selection tool

Tags: qgis, symbology

How do I change the way selected polygons look. Instead of being highlighted in yellow, I would like to have them with a red border and no fill color.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to GSE. Please add which software you use, add more context in your question, eventually links or image. The more detailed your question is, the more chance you have to have answers and let it be to others.

Comment: Using QGIS just open the project properties in the project menu. First tab, right at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to Project > Project properties

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Is there a way to change the color to transparent, but put a border around the selection?

Comment: not in the usual way.  Maybe with python